# Digital certificate to JPEG

Tags: windows, certificate, x509certificate, digital-signature

Is it possible to inject a digital SSL certificate to an image? I know how to sign an executable file (.exe) file or a PowerShell script (.ps1) but is it possible with an image (JPEG)?

Comment: @Xearinox, like any digital signature mechanism: prove to its recipient who it comes from and that it hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: What does this have to do with SSL, though?

Comment: What another alterantive existe for this purpose? It is required a timestamp and validate the indentity of the user. It should works everywhere, is not valid and audit policy in a folder.

Comment: Jpeg is not designed to work with digital signatures. You may try use custom marker in jpeg for this, but rather use pdf as mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a detached CMS signature and pass it along with the JPEG file. The benefit is that the original JPEG file is not modified in any way.

Another idea that comes to my mind is putting JPEG into say PDF and sign the PDF using PDF signing techniques. But this won't let you easily extract the JPEG (the user will be able to easily view it though).

Answer (score 1):

I was the co-inventor of the "dSIG" chunk that involves digital signatures to be embedded in PNGs. I believe this is more about what you are really after, you may want to have a look at the [specification](ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/png/documents/signatures/index.html).

You could use a degenerated CMS signature only consisting of certificates but with no actual SignerInfo to just add certificates to a PNG image that way, but I would assume that actual signatures might be more about what you really want?

The beauty of the approach is that software not aware of dSIG will continue to display the image as if it weren't signed at all, it will simply ignore the additional dSIG chunk.

Comment: Sounds very interesting. Is this specification actual and supported (by implementors of viewing software) or it, as the URL suggests, a history?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I didn't link to the official URL on ftp.simplesystems.org, fixed that - thanks for the hint :) Unfortunately, I'm not aware of support in popular viewers, seemed too exotic at the time, I guess. I've still got plans to publish some open source tools if I get the time. It's by no means as powerful as a good steganographic watermark feature would be, but I still believe it could turn out to be useful...

Comment: It would be nice to see more widespread support. My interest is pragmatic - we'd implement such support if there were interest and widespread adoption of the extension. I'll add an idea to our wishlist, let's see.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Great, I'd be happy to see this adopted - please feel free to contact me if I you have any questions about it!

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Looking forward to it, finally some interest in dSIG ;)